# Derivative of $0$-form

Tags: differential-forms

[image]

Rudin states that $1$-form $xdy$ is not the derivative of any $0$-form.

By contradiction, suppose that that exists $0$-form whose derivative is $xdy$. Then $f\in C'$ and $df=xdy$. But $d^2f=dx\land dy\neq 0$. But how to apply part (b) of theorem 10.20? For right application our $f$ must be from $C''$ but it's from $C'$.

I would be very thankful for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if $f\in C'$ and satisfies $$df=xdy$$ it means that $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0 \text{ and } \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=x.$$
And as you can see each partial derivative is again of class $C'$ and thus $f$ has to be of class $C''$.

Now, stating that $d^2f\neq 0$ is just an other way to notice that the Schwarz theorem doesn't apply : $$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\neq \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Since $d^2f=dx\land dy\neq 0$ but by part b) we have that $d^2f=0$ since  $f\in C''$. Contradiction.Right?

Comment: Yes of course, no problem with that. I was only pointed out that the fact $d^2f=0$ is a consequence of the Scharz theorem, stating differently.

Comment: Dear @bebop. Can you look at my question please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756510/theorem-10-22-from-pma-rudin