# Theorem 10.22 from PMA RUdin

Tags: differential-forms

[image]

We know that $(dy_I)_T=dt_{i_1}\land \dots \land dt_{i_k}$ and using definition 10.18 we get $$d((dy_{I})_{T})=d1\land dt_{i_1}\land \dots \land dt_{i_k}=0$$ since $dc=0$ for any $c\in \mathbb{R}^1$.

Are my reasonings true? Note that in my method i didn't use that $T\in C''$ and theorem 10.20.

I would be v ery grateful for any answer.

Comment: That's not what 10.18 is telling you: $dt_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dt_{i_k}$ is not written of the form $\sum_{J}b_J(x)dx_J$.

Comment: Why? In this case we have only one $J$ which is $\{i_1,\dots, i_k\}$ increaing $k$-index and $b_J(x)=1$.

Comment: @Bebop, I wrote comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, observe that each $t_{i_j}$ is a function so that $dt_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dt_{i_k}$ is not of the form $\sum_J b_J(x)dx_J$.

Let's take an example to understand that point with $T:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ given by $$T(x)=(x_1,x_2)=(x_1x_2,x_1+x_2,x_1^3)$$
so that $$t_1(x)=x_1x_2, \ t_2(x)=x_1+x_2, \ t_3(x)=x_1^3.$$
Hence, $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}dt_1=x_2dx_1+x_1dx_2 \\ dt_2=dx_1+dx_2 \\ dt_3=3x_1^2dx_1\end{array}\right.$$
and $$dt_1\wedge dt_3 = \left(x_2dx_1+x_1dx_2\right)\wedge \left( 3x_1^2dx_1\right) = 3x_1^3dx_2\wedge dx_1$$ which is of the form $\sum_{J} b_J(x)dx_J$ so you can apply rule 10.18 : $$\begin{align*}
d(dt_1\wedge dt_3) & =d\left(3x_1^3dx_2\wedge dx_1\right)\\
& =6x_1^2dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_1\\
& =-6x_1^2dx_1\wedge dx_1\wedge dx_2\\
& = 0\end{align*}$$
since $dx_i\wedge dx_j=-dx_j\wedge dx_i$.

But, Rudin is actually saying that, using theorem 10.20 (a) and (b), one can directly notice that :
$$\begin{align*}
d(dt_1\wedge dt_3) & =d(dt_1)\wedge dt_3 - dt_1\wedge d(dt_3) \\
& = 0\wedge dt_3 - dt_1\wedge 0 \\ & =0\end{align*}$$
where the minus comes from the 1-form $dt_1$.

It works the same with any $T:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and $dt_{_i1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dt_{i_k}$ instead of $dt_1\wedge dt_3$.

Comment: Nice answer but I have some question. I state that $d((dy_I)_T)=0$ from definition 10.18 because after expanding it has form $\sum \limits_{J}b_J(x)dx_J$. Am I right?

Comment: My point is that: using definition 10.18 we don't need that $T\in C''$.

Comment: We need the assumption $T\in C''$ because we compute at some point $d(dt_i))$. About your first comment, no, a differential form $\omega$ can always be written of the form $\omega=\sum_Jb_J(x)dx_J$, stating that $d\omega=0$ comes from the function $b_J(x)$.

Comment: I guess that you didn't understand my question: I am stating that $dt_{i_1}\land \dots \land dt_{i_k}$ can be written in the form $\sum _{J}b_J(x)dx_J$. That's what I mean.

Comment: So we both agree with that point.

Comment: May I ask you another question please? He wrote that if $f$ is a $0$-form then $f_T(x)=f(T(x))$. How he got that? I assume the following: By definition 10.21 if $\omega=f(y)$ then mapping $T$ transforms $w$ into $0$-form $\omega_T$ such that $\omega_T=f(T(x))$. How he get that $f_T(x)=f(T(x))$? Also $x$ and $y$ little bit confuses me.

Comment: A $0$-form is just a function, thus if you look at (65) in Rudin's book, there is no $dy_I$ and thus no $dt_{i_j}$ in (67) appearing. So $\omega_T$ becomes $\omega\circ T$.

Comment: Could you please help explain what role does (70) plays in proving $d(\omega_{T})=d(f_{T}) \land (dy_{I})_{T}=(df)_{T} \land (dy_{I})_{T}=((df) \land dy_{I})_{T}=(d\omega)_{T}$ where $\omega=fdy_{I}$ and $\omega_{T}=f_{T}(x)(dy_{I})_{T}$