# Theorem 10.22 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Here's part of the proof of theorem 10.22 [Theorem 10.22 from PMA RUdin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756510/theorem-10-22-from-pma-rudin)

The rest part is

> Assume now $\omega=fdy_{I}$. Then $\omega_{T}=f_{T}(x)(dy_{I})_{T}$
>
> the preceding calculation leads to $$d(\omega_{T})=d(f_{T}) \land (dy_{I})_{T}=(df)_{T} \land (dy_{I})_{T}=((df) \land dy_{I})_{T}=(d\omega)_{T}$$

My question is that, Rudin said the first equality of the above equation follows from $(70)$, can someone help me explain why? $(70)$ said $d((dy_{I})_{T})=0$, how do we get the first equality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know from a previous theorem (see your post [Theorem 10.20 Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501113/theorem-10-20-rudin)) that $$d(\omega_T)=d(f_T (dy_I)_T)=d(f_T)\wedge (dy_I)_T+f_T\wedge d((dy_I)_T),$$ and since $d((dy_I)_T)=0,$ we know that $d(\omega_T)=d(f_T)\wedge (dy_I)_T.$

Comment: That's right, but the theorem 10.20 only apples to wedge product $(\omega \land \lambda$), but here $f_T (dy_I)_T$ is multiplication, I think we can directly get the equality without using $(70)$, is my thought correct?

Comment: The wedge of a function and a form is just multiplication. Same reason as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502167/wedge-product-of-0-and-dx

Comment: This makes sense if we regard this as the wedge of a function and a form, I mean can we just use the definition of differentiation? $d(\omega_{T})=d(f_{T})\land(dy_I)_T$, so we don't need to use $(70)$

Comment: You could just use the definition of $d$, sure. You'll just be effectively repeating some of the derivations of past results.